# Unknown character ordering

Tags: python, sorting, unix, character, ascii

I'm sorting a large list of values, and I'm using a sort.exe file [(site here](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/), [zip file with sort.exe here)](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/UnxUpdates.zip) which is a port of the UNIX 'sort' command for Windows.  However, I can't figure out what order it's sorting it in.  So, I took the ASCII characters list, and ran the sort file on it to see the order it produced.  **Does anyone know what character ordering this is, or more specifically how I can implement it in Python?**

**Edit**:
chcp was initially 437 (USA), I also tried with 65001 (Unicode), both giving me the same output.

```
╔═══════╦══════════╗
║ ASCII ║ SORT.EXE ║
╠═══════╬══════════╣
║ !     ║ '        ║
║ "     ║ -        ║
║ #     ║ !        ║
║ $     ║ "        ║
║ %     ║ #        ║
║ &     ║ $        ║
║ '     ║ %        ║
║ (     ║ &        ║
║ )     ║ (        ║
║ *     ║ )        ║
║ +     ║ *        ║
║ ,     ║ ,        ║
║ -     ║ .        ║
║ .     ║ /        ║
║ /     ║ :        ║
║ 0     ║ ;        ║
║ 1     ║ ?        ║
║ 2     ║ @        ║
║ 3     ║ [        ║
║ 4     ║ \        ║
║ 5     ║ ]        ║
║ 6     ║ ^        ║
║ 7     ║ _        ║
║ 8     ║ `        ║
║ 9     ║ {        ║
║ :     ║ |        ║
║ ;     ║ }        ║
║ <     ║ ~        ║
║ =     ║ +        ║
║ >     ║ <        ║
║ ?     ║ =        ║
║ @     ║ >        ║
║ A     ║ 0        ║
║ B     ║ 1        ║
║ C     ║ 2        ║
║ D     ║ 3        ║
║ E     ║ 4        ║
║ F     ║ 5        ║
║ G     ║ 6        ║
║ H     ║ 7        ║
║ I     ║ 8        ║
║ J     ║ 9        ║
║ K     ║ a        ║
║ L     ║ A        ║
║ M     ║ b        ║
║ N     ║ B        ║
║ O     ║ c        ║
║ P     ║ C        ║
║ Q     ║ d        ║
║ R     ║ D        ║
║ S     ║ e        ║
║ T     ║ E        ║
║ U     ║ f        ║
║ V     ║ F        ║
║ W     ║ g        ║
║ X     ║ G        ║
║ Y     ║ h        ║
║ Z     ║ H        ║
║ [     ║ i        ║
║ \     ║ I        ║
║ ]     ║ j        ║
║ ^     ║ J        ║
║ _     ║ k        ║
║ `     ║ K        ║
║ a     ║ l        ║
║ b     ║ L        ║
║ c     ║ m        ║
║ d     ║ M        ║
║ e     ║ n        ║
║ f     ║ N        ║
║ g     ║ o        ║
║ h     ║ O        ║
║ i     ║ p        ║
║ j     ║ P        ║
║ k     ║ q        ║
║ l     ║ Q        ║
║ m     ║ r        ║
║ n     ║ R        ║
║ o     ║ s        ║
║ p     ║ S        ║
║ q     ║ t        ║
║ r     ║ T        ║
║ s     ║ u        ║
║ t     ║ U        ║
║ u     ║ v        ║
║ v     ║ V        ║
║ w     ║ w        ║
║ x     ║ W        ║
║ y     ║ x        ║
║ z     ║ X        ║
║ {     ║ y        ║
║ |     ║ Y        ║
║ }     ║ z        ║
║ ~     ║ Z        ║
╚═══════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Can you post where did you got the `sort.exe`. Maybe there's some source code to figure it out :)

Comment: Also, can you please output the result of the `chcp` command on your Windows machine? Maybe your current encoding has something to do with it.

Comment: I don't know how to duplicate this sort order in Python, but if you do `set LC_ALL C` in the console, that will *probably* make subsequent invocations of this `sort.exe` use ASCII sort order.

Comment: `sort.exe` takes a locale option; the default is Microsoft proprietary case-insensitive sorting.

Comment: @Zack Running set LC_ALL=C in the cmd window made it run with ASCII sort order.  Thank you!  Microsoft's default sort order is weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very similar to `sort -df` (`-d` for dictionary order, `-f` for ignore case) on the GNU `sort` I have. However, the `'` and `-` being at the top is different. Sounds like this may have been solved in the comments, but for future reference:

To sort strings in custom order in Python, one way is to use `maketrans()` and `translate()` in your sort key, like so:

```
ascii = '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~'
mapped = '\'-!"#$%&()*,./:;?@[\\]^_`{|}~+<=>0123456789aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ'
trans = str.maketrans(mapped, ascii)
print("".join(sorted(ascii, key=lambda s: s.translate(trans)))) # prints mapped
```